# How to add log4j2 configuration file as system property?

Tags: java, logging, java-8, log4j2

I have been trying to pass the log configuration url through system property but it is resulting in an error.

```
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

I have passed the system property as follows:

```
<sysproperty key="log4j.configurationFile" value="file:${_real_dir}/config/project.log4j2" />
```

Here project.log4j2 is the configuration file. How should I change the sysproperty key to make this work?

Comment: Eh - the loader tries to infer the configuration type from the file extension, and I think log4j2 isn't one of the known extensions. Have you tried making the filename's extension match one of the supported ones? `.properties`, `.yaml`, '`.yml`, `.json`, `.jsn` or `.xml`? This is from the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) on this is relatively clear - you need to make the extension of the configuration type match the file format, so the factory can generate the correct configuration parser.

The [ConfigurationFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html) documentation indicates 4 logging file formats: Json, XML, Yaml and Property file format.

You need to make the file extension for the configuration match the file format, so if your configuration is xml, then make the file extension `.xml`, etc.

So if the config is in xml, your systemproperty should look like:

```
<sysproperty key="log4j.configurationFile" value="file:${_real_dir}/config/project.log4j2.xml" />
```